# Excel | Generate Random Number | Avoid Duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

1st timer, so hope I'm following the rules...

**BACKGROUND**

I have a database of ~500 entries (and growing) within an Excel 2010 workbook.
The enties are Q&A's for a quiz.
The data is formated into 3 columns:

- Col A = Fixed Q number (1, 2, 3, etc)
- Col B = Question text
- Col C = Answer Text.

The next sheet in the workbook is where I generate the random shortlist of questions for a set quiz (in my case 80 Q's) as follows:

- Col A = Available Q numbers
- Col B = RAND() formula to generate a random number
- Col C = Using the following formula I then use the RAND() output to
  generate a unique list of 80 Questions for a "Quiz Set":

`=INDEX(ROW($2:$5001),RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$5001))`

As the RAND() function is volatile I have created a Macro that takes a snapshot of the random 80 numbers.  It cut & pastes these to a 3rd worksheet, which I then run VLOOKUP against to pull the matching Q&A for the Question Number generated.

**QUESTION**

As this is for a monthly Quiz I would like to avoid repeating questions from the DB of Q&A's each month.  Based on the number of questions it's been agreed that if we can avoid repeats over a rolling 4 months that would be OK.
Is there a way that I can demising the list of available questions each time the macro runs so that I remove the question numbers used over the previous 4 runs of the macro?
I've googled all I can think of to get an answer, but I'm either not using the right search criteria, or it just can't find an answer.
As I found the original information on creating the 80 question shortlist using the INDEX function listed above I thought I'd start here.

Comment: You're going to need to store the "used" questions somewhere (i.e., a hidden worksheet) or set a flag (e.g., in Column D), indicating which questions have been used (and when they were used).  Then, you can use this information to create a dictionary of available questions, and pull from that.  Then, you have to update your list of used questions, remembering to mark as "unused" the questions which were used long enough ago to re-enter the rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to retain a list of previous quiz questions chosen somewhere.

changing column B to be `=RAND()-COUNTIF(Range_Where_Previous_q_listed,A2)`, the random number will become negative for the questions where the question was listed previously, and will then fall to the bottom of the `RANK` function.

Comment: Brilliant, this sounds like a step in the right direction.

I'm off to see if I can find a way of only keeping a set amount of question numbers in the "Previous" list.

I'll report back once I have updates...

Thanks